# How do I return array from AJAX as JSON and read results

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I need help once again. I am trying to return a multiple rows of a table from AJAX in JSON and place those values in textboxs. Here is the code I have.

HTML:

```
       $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */

            type: "POST", 
            url: "actionprt.php", 
            data: {"loadnumber": loadnumber},
            dataType: 'json', 

           success: function(data) {

            $("#CustomerName").val(result.Customer);
            $("#CustomerAddress").val(result.Address);
                    }                        
            }); /* END OF AJAX */   

     $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */

            type: "POST", 
            url: "actionprt2.php", 
            data: {"loadnumber": loadnumber},
            dataType: 'json', 

           success: function(data) {

            $("#prtdescription1").val(result.data[0]);
            $("#prtmethod1").val(result.data[1]);
                    }                        
            }); /* END OF AJAX */
```

PHP:

```
      $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `tblExpDescription`.`Description`,`Method`,`PONumber`,`Gallons`,`DollarAmount` FROM `tblExpenses` LEFT JOIN `tblExpDescription` ON (`tblExpenses`.`Description` = `tblExpDescription`.`ExpenseID`) WHERE (`tblExpenses`.`LoadID`= ?);");

$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["loadnumber"]); /* PARAMETIZE THIS VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY */
$stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
$stmt->bind_result($Description, $Method, $PONumber, $Gallons, $Amount); 
/* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES */
$stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULTS */
$stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */

/* RETURN THIS DATA TO THE MAIN FILE */
echo json_encode(array("Description" => $Description, "Method" => $Method, "PONumber" => $PONumber, "Gallons" => $Gallons, "Amount" => $Amount));
}
```

This will return on row, but there can be 0 rows or many rows. How do I return this array to the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how come you get `data` and use `result.data` try to use it like this

```
success: function(data) {
   $.each(data , function(key , value){
      console.log(key);
      console.log(value);
      console.log(value.des);
      console.log(value.met);
   });
  }                        
}); /* END OF AJAX */
```

Comment: that give me this error on the $.each line:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: this is still not working. Maybe its something else, let me describe.
I have a ajax call that queries a database, retreives one record and returns those values to the Juery and fills in my text boxes. That works great thanks all. The part I cant get to work, is I also need to make another ajax call to retreive multiple rows from same database, seperate table. the way it is now, I call the first ajax, and then call the second. is that proper? I have edited the question above to help describe.

Comment: @Musicdad I think its not bad to make 2 ajax call if each of them has a different propose .. I just wondered how you pass data >> success: function(data) {  and get values by result.Customer .. I think it should be success: function(result) { << not (data) .. and about your code if 1st ajax works good  try to make a same thing with the 2nd ajax and return just one record to be sure everything works good .. and then console.log(data); in success to see what you will get .. and let me know then what the console.log(data) retrieve

Comment: I used the same code as first ajax (which is mysqli) and it returned 1 record as expected. then I changed it to  mysql to get more then 1 record (because i didnt know how to "bind" multiple rows) and I get nothing from console.

Comment: @Musicdad don't use mysql instead of mysqli .. keep use mysqli even its returned just one result .. so maybe the problem with your query and query just returned just one row .. so keep using mysqli .. and 1st :echo out results in your php file and run it directly .. 2nd:if it gives you more than one row  so your php and query is fine .. so the problem will be in array or in returned data to ajax

Comment: I am updating my php file above with the current code. I cant figure out how to put the values in an array. Please help.

Comment: I'm making progress. Here is the ouput for console key, val

key:  0
val:    Object {Description: "Tractor", Method: "FC", PONumber: "", Gallons: 157.216, Amount: 385.02}
key:  1
val:    Object {Description: "DEF", Method: "FC", PONumber: "", Gallons: 10.375, Amount: 28}

Comment: @Musicdad finally it working? .. Congratulations .. Very Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

for others. here is my final working code.

Jquery:
        $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */

```
        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "actionprt2.php", /* THE FILE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
        data: {"loadnumber": loadnumber}, /* THE DATA WE WILL PASS TO action.php */
        dataType: 'json', /* DATA TYPE THAT WILL BE RETURNED FROM action.php */
        success: function(data) {
            i = 1
           $.each(data , function(key , value){
            $.each(value , function(key2 , value2){

             $("#prt" + key2 + i).val(value2);
             $("#prt" + key2 + i).val(value2);
             $("#prt" + key2 + i).val(value2);
             $("#prt" + key2 + i).val(value2);
             $("#prt" + key2 + i).val(value2);

              });
              i++
           });
          }                        
        }); /* END OF AJAX */
```

php:

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `tblExpDescription`.`Description`,`Method`,`PONumber`,`Gallons`,`DollarAmount` FROM `tblExpenses` LEFT JOIN `tblExpDescription` ON (`tblExpenses`.`Description` = `tblExpDescription`.`ExpenseID`) WHERE (`tblExpenses`.`LoadID`= ?);");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["loadnumber"]); /* PARAMETIZE THIS VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($Description, $Method, $PONumber, $Gallons, $Amount); 
    /* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES */
    $detail = array();  
    while($stmt->fetch()) {           
        $detail[] = array('Description' => $Description, 'Method' => $Method, 'PONumber' => $PONumber, 'Gallons' => $Gallons, 'Amount' => $Amount);
}
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */

    /* RETURN THIS DATA TO THE MAIN FILE */
    echo json_encode($detail);
    } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY loadnumber */
```